# C# Textrenderer - Measuring smaller fontsize results in larger size

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, textrenderer

I am trying to measure the size of a string given a certain font using the TextRenderer class. Despite the fact that i tried measuring it with 3 different approaches (Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges, Graphics.MeasureString, TextRenderer.MeasureText) and they all give me different results without being accurate, i've stumbled across something else.
Measuring the same string `START` with the same font using a fontsize of 7 and 8, the fontsize 7 measurement turns out to be wider than the the fontsize 8 measurement.

Here's the code i use:

```
Font f1 = new Font("Arial", 7, FontStyle.Regular);
Font f2 = new Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular);
Size s1 = TextRenderer.MeasureText("START", f1);
Size s2 = TextRenderer.MeasureText("START", f2);
```

The result is `s1` having a `width` of 41 and a `height` of 13 while `s2` having a `width` of 40 and a `height` of 14.

Why would a smaller font result in a larger width?

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce. Here I get 44,15 and 53,16 .Try SizeF instead! My monitor has 120dpi.

Comment: Note that all except  Graphics.MeasureString with StringFormat.TypographicGenic add some whitespace to allow you to string the output together without overlapping the words.

Comment: @TaW my monitor is running on the default 96dpi. TextRenderer doesn't offer any methods that would measure a string resulting in a SizeF.
I don't mind the size being larger due to additonal padding, i was just wondering how a smaller font size results in larger width.

Comment: It is a 96 dpi measurement.  And correct, 8 point text is actually wider than 7 point at 96 dpi.  You'll have to get used to the mysteries and inaccuracies of measuring text, TrueType hinting, pixel-grid fitting and typographic features like glyph overhang, ligatures and kerning make it an inexact art.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To address specifically *why* it would be possible for a larger font to produce a smaller width, I put together this sample console app.  It's worth noting that I adjust the 7 & 8 font sizes to 7.5 & 8.25, respectively, as this is what size `TextRenderer` evaluates them as internally.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FontSizeDifference
{
    static class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct ABCFLOAT
        {
            public float abcfA;
            public float abcfB;
            public float abcfC;
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern bool GetCharABCWidthsFloat(IntPtr hdc, int iFirstChar, int iLastChar, [Out] ABCFLOAT[] lpABCF);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "SelectObject", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hdc, IntPtr obj);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
        static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct KERNINGPAIR
        {
            public ushort wFirst;
            public ushort wSecond;
            public int iKernAmount;
        }

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern int GetKerningPairs(IntPtr hdc, int nNumPairs, [Out] KERNINGPAIR[] lpkrnpair);

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            var fonts = new[] {
                new Font("Arial", 7.5f, FontStyle.Regular),
                new Font("Arial", 8.25f, FontStyle.Regular)
            };
            string textToMeasure = "START";

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                IntPtr hDC = g.GetHdc();

                foreach (Font font in fonts)
                {
                    float totalWidth = 0F;
                    IntPtr hFont = font.ToHfont();

                    // Apply the font to dc
                    SelectObject(hDC, hFont);

                    int pairCount = GetKerningPairs(hDC, short.MaxValue, null);
                    var lpkrnpair = new KERNINGPAIR[pairCount];
                    GetKerningPairs(hDC, pairCount, lpkrnpair);

                    Console.WriteLine("\r\n" + font.ToString());

                    for (int ubound = textToMeasure.Length - 1, i = 0; i <= ubound; ++i)
                    {
                        char c = textToMeasure[i];
                        ABCFLOAT characterWidths = GetCharacterWidths(hDC, c);
                        float charWidth = (characterWidths.abcfA + characterWidths.abcfB + characterWidths.abcfC);
                        totalWidth += charWidth;

                        int kerning = 0;
                        if (i < ubound)
                        {
                            kerning = GetKerningBetweenCharacters(lpkrnpair, c, textToMeasure[i + 1]).iKernAmount;
                            totalWidth += kerning;
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine(c + ": " + (charWidth + kerning) + " (" + charWidth + " + " + kerning + ")");
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Total width: " + totalWidth);

                    DeleteObject(hFont);
                }

                g.ReleaseHdc(hDC);
            }
        }

        static KERNINGPAIR GetKerningBetweenCharacters(KERNINGPAIR[] lpkrnpair, char first, char second)
        {
            return lpkrnpair.Where(x => (x.wFirst == first) && (x.wSecond == second)).FirstOrDefault();
        }

        static ABCFLOAT GetCharacterWidths(IntPtr hDC, char character)
        {
            ABCFLOAT[] values = new ABCFLOAT[1];
            GetCharABCWidthsFloat(hDC, character, character, values);
            return values[0];
        }
    }
}
```

For each font size, it outputs the width of each character, including kerning.  At 96 DPI, for me, this results in:

> [Font: Name=Arial, Size=7.5, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
>   S: 7 (7 + 0)
>   T: 6 (7 + -1)
>   A: 7 (7 + 0)
>   R: 7 (7 + 0)
>   T: 7 (7 + 0)
>   Total width: 34
>
> [Font: Name=Arial, Size=8.25, Units=3, GdiCharSet=1, GdiVerticalFont=False]
>   S: 7 (7 + 0)
>   T: 5 (6 + -1)
>   A: 8 (8 + 0)
>   R: 7 (7 + 0)
>   T: 6 (6 + 0)
>   Total width: 33

Though I've obviously not captured the exact formula for measurements made by `TextRenderer`, it does illustrate the same width-discrepancy.  At font size 7, all characters are 7 in width.  However, at font size 8, the character widths begin to vary, some larger, some smaller, ultimately adding up to a smaller width.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like `TextRenderer.MeasureText` is giving correct value, however smaller font has bigger letter-spacing for some glyphs.

Below you can see how it looks for `"TTTTTTTTT"` text. Upper one is **Arial 7**, bottom one is **Arial 8**.

For bigger font there is no space between letters.

[image]